# Undetectable issue with large multi-color batch ascii art

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a strange issue where some large multi-colored ascii art will display irregularly, either only displaying the bottom 1/5 or so of the art, or the top 9 lines of the art if they are commented and un-commented.

The following batch code is being used to multi-color stuff.

```
:c
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "s=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 s %3
exit /b
:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined DEL call :initColorPrint
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd .
':
cd \
set "s=!%~2!"
for %%n in (^"^

^") do (
  set "s=!s:\=%%~n\%%~n!"
  set "s=!s:/=%%~n/%%~n!"
  set "s=!s::=%%~n:%%~n!"
)
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%s in ("!s!") do (
  if "!" equ "" setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  if %%s==\ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else if %%s==/ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "/.\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else (
    >colorPrint.txt (echo %%s\..\')
    findstr /a:%~1 /f:colorPrint.txt "."
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  )
)
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
popd
exit /b
:initColorPrint
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H&for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%A %%A"
<nul >"%cd%\'" set /p "=."
subst ': "%cd%" >nul
exit /b
:cleanupColorPrint
2>nul del "%cd%\'"
2>nul del "%cd%\colorPrint.txt"
>nul subst ': /d
exit /b
```

https://pastebin.com/Z1CKjwWR

but the real meat of the issue comes with trying to display this anime girl

https://pastebin.com/W0w1AtNN

Is anyone able to tell what causes the display issues, and why? None of my experimentation got me anywhere.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? I just ran your code and got [this](https://imgur.com/i4KkdIM), which as far as I can tell is correct.

Comment: How is your command prompt configured? It's possible that the issue has to do with something on my computer specifically.

Comment: I'm not using legacy mode and in order for your picture to not have spaces between each line, I extended the width of the command prompt. Everything else is the default value.

Comment: that makes the situation more confusing, in that case. I've ran this script on 3 different devices and every single one of them outputs [this](https://i.imgur.com/AjYvKQP.png)

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? That dark blue on the command prompt title bar makes it look really old.

Comment: All devices I tested it on are running variations of Windows 10, I just like the old Windows aesthetic so I set my stuff to look like that. Nothing has been configured with the cmd properties on any of the computers, though.

Comment: I just realized that the one tweak to your code that I didn't mention is that instead of using `&` to chain commands together, I put each `call` on its own line. I undid that tweak and got your results. Using `&` to chain commands is always a bad move.

Comment: I would also have immediately replaced the ampersands with new lines too. This leaves you with `1780` lines of individual `Call` commands. However, I would not ever advise anyone to do something like this, it's childish, unnecessary, and worst of all, based upon the example posted by @SomethingDark, doesn't look like an anime girl on my mobile, and certainly wouldn't be recognisable on a monitor, unless viewed from the opposite side of the building.

Comment: If your using windows 10, color changes would be done far more efficiently using ANSI color codes. [An example of them in use for a batch GOL can be found here.](https://pastebin.com/yuDKYvyb)